# Primefaces Data Exporter with Primefaces Editor

Tags: primefaces

Is it possible  to export the editor data to pdf using Data exporter of primefaces.

I tried with following code but it didnt worked.

```
 <p:editor value="#{mailBean.mail}" id="editor">

    </p:editor>

    <p:commandLink>
    <p:graphicImage value="/images/pdf.gif" /> 
<p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="editor" fileName="files" pageOnly="true"/> 
    </p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

No its not

from the user guide:

> DataExporter is handy for exporting data listed using a Primefaces Datatable to various formats
>   such as excel, pdf, csv and xml.

more from the user guide

> Target must
>   point to a PrimeFaces Datatable

**Edit**

What you could try is : Integrate [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) editor in your project and take a look at this thread [HTML to PDF demo](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=25663) , here is a direct link [WYSIWYG Editor Export to PDF](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/)

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Data exporter publisher button must not ajax, and target value should refer to an datatable, also you need **itext 2.1.7 Optional DataExporter (PDF)** **apache poi 3.7 Optional DataExporter** libraries (Excel)..

Even if they are all right, data exporter not stable yet, it depends your datatable. For example it can not export data when you use dynamic column with column group.

I prefer export your own documents using **itext** libraries, its also more flexible.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

if the Target must point to a PrimeFaces Datatable , then how the below code is possible
this is from primeface site .(http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartExport.jsf)

```
    <p:lineChart value="#{chartBean.linearModel}" legendPosition="e" zoom="true"  
                         title="Linear Chart" minY="0" maxY="10" style="width:500px;height:300px" widgetVar="chart"/>  

<p:commandButton type="button" value="Export" icon="ui-icon-extlink" onclick="exportChart()"/>  

<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" modal="true" header="Chart as an Image">  
    <p:outputPanel id="output" layout="block" style="width:500px;height:300px"/>  
</p:dialog>  

function exportChart() {  
    //export image  
    $('#output').empty().append(PF('chart').exportAsImage());  

    //show the dialog  
    PF('dlg').show();  
}
```

here the source file is a chart and using the function exportChart() get the exported data as image.that means we can export any data not only the primeface datatable.